# Padding alternative to margin: auto

Tags: css

Currently working on the default Woocommerce slider that has square thumbnails with a max height and width of 100% set to its images. These images are almost never square. Some are either very tall or very wide leaving a lot of white space around the images inside the thumbnail, which is fine visually.

The problem is that you have to click the images to select the slide. This means small images will result in a lot of missclicks and frustration. Is there a way to set a padding to fill up the white space around the images? Like `margin:auto;` does for example.

Example image (thumbnail is about 75x75 pixels):

[image]

These are the CSS styles I added to get the images centered in the thumbnails and some other minor adjustments to the active state:

```
.flex-control-thumbs {

            li {
                position: relative;
                width: 21.25%!important;
                margin-right: 5%!important;
                border-width: 1px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: $light-gray;
                transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
                overflow: hidden;
                background-color: $white;

                &:nth-child(4n) {
                    margin-right: 0!important;
                }

                &.flex-parent-active {
                    border-bottom-width: 3px;
                    border-bottom-color: $primary-color;
                }

                img {
                    position: relative;
                    top: 50%;
                    transform: translateY(-50%);
                    max-height: 100%;
                    padding: 5px;

                    &.flex-active:after {
                        content: "";
                        position: absolute;
                        bottom: 0;
                        left: 0;
                        right: 0;
                        height: 3px;
                        background-color: $primary-color;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you post a example picture of what you looking for?

Comment: Surely you mean "images with extreme aspect ratio" instead of "small images"? Since you're stretching them (although using `max-width` and `max-height` alone is insufficient for the purpose, I believe) it's not about the pixel count, it's about their aspect ratio. Anyway, use an anchor element (`a`) to wrap an image, that's what it's for. Define its `href` attribute to refer to the slide / actual image. Your question is an example of the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) -- you don't need the padding analogue of `margin: auto`, you need to describe what you are trying to design.

Comment: without any code that shows your issue and tries, only a cristal ball could really help here ! ;)

Comment: @amn I did mean extreme aspect ratio ;-) This is the standard Woocommerce slider so I did not build it myself. I'm not sure if I should alter the HTML too much as I might mess up the the way it functions. I don't mind adding CSS and jQuery though.

Comment: @G-Cyr I'll see if I can get my hands on a crystal ball ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just add padding or a defined width that should do the trick margin auto arainges the objects not defines its space occupation.

Comment: I've tried but the images shrink when I add more padding and changing the width/height would just stretch the images.

Comment: Make a div and alter its size not the images

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting a fixed width for your thumbnail divs and then set a background image for them, or better yet just edit your thumbnail images to all be the same size. This way you can have tall images but they would also include that extra space on the sides naturally, either as transparent png or same background color jpg

Comment: Good solutions but in my case this doesn't work. For some reason the Woocommerce slider doesn't like the background image solution too much. Fixable but the result would have been turned down anyways since the images would have been cropped. Editing the thumbnail images would be a last case scenario since we're talking about thousands of images that would have to be resized.